# Docker services not linked - WordPress not connecting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

This is literally my first time using Docker. I have a WordPress site and I used https://phpdocker.io/ to generate some files, including `docker-compose.yml`

I placed the package contents in my project's root and then tried to run `docker-compose up -d` and I can connect to my MySQL where I load my SQL dump and then I go to http://localhost, but it says that "Connection can't be established", when enabling debugging I get:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /application/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
>   Error establishing a database connection

I added `links`, but that didn't help. This is what my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
    ###############################################################################
#                          Generated on local                                 #
###############################################################################
version: "3.1"
services:

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: local-wordpress-redis

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: local-wordpress-mysql
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=local
      - MYSQL_USER=orbuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: local-wordpress-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./local/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis

  php-fpm:
    build: local/php-fpm
    container_name: local-wordpress-php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./local/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
```

`wp-config.php`

```
<?php
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache

define('DB_NAME', 'local');
define('DB_USER', 'orbuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypass');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

define('AUTH_KEY',         'xx');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'xx');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'xx');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'xx');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'xx');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'xx');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'xx');

$table_prefix  = 'ftom_';

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', '/');

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: What is your host name in the PHP container?

Comment: I have no clue. Can you tell me how to check?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `wp-config.php` file as well.

Comment: It may be something like the `WORDPRESS_DB_NAME` settings on https://github.com/mjstealey/wordpress-nginx-docker

Comment: @cabrerahector I added wp-config.php as you requested.

Comment: Not entirely sure as I'm pretty new to Docker as well but try setting `DB_HOST` to `mysql` and check again.

Comment: @cabrerahector That didn't work - says wrong credentials

Answer (score 0):

DB_HOST should be set to name of container: mysql.
At the moment your wordpress is looking for database at its own loop.

Comment: I tried that, but got this: https://screenshots.firefox.com/dbXSxUw8c2OVuLPV/localhost